# Trouble opening files from a list of closed python files?

Tags: python, file, typeerror

I have a python list `list_of_docs` which contains a list of closed .txt files. My goal is to count how many files contain a certain word.

```
def contains(word):
  count = 0
  for file in range list_of_docs:
    current_doc = open(list_of_docs[file], 'r')
    text = current_doc.read()
    line = text.split()
    if word in line:
      count += 1
```

When I call this function, I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

The files in `list_of_docs`, are actually opened earlier in the code. I close them and reopen them again during this method call because because without closing them I get a `Too many files open` error.

How I can fix this `TypeError`?

Comment: `open()` expects filename (not handler to closed file) so `list_of_docs` must be list of filenames.

Answer (score 1):

`file` isn't an index, it's already the item from the list.

So you would have: (closed files have a `.name` attribute)

```
for file in range list_of_docs:
    current_doc = open(file.name, 'r')
    ...
```

I think you should refactor your code to use a list of the filenames instead

```
  for filename in range list_of_filenames:
    current_doc = open(filename, 'r')
      ...
      # still need to close the file
```

To make sure the file is closed, use a context manager

```
for filename in range list_of_filenames:    
    with open(filename, 'r') as current_doc:
        text = current_doc.read()
        line = text.split()
        if word in line:
          count += 1
```